# Accessing rtpsession inside webrtcbin

Tags: webrtc, gstreamer

It is possible to access the internal statistics of `rtpbin` using its `get-internal-session` property.

`g_signal_emit_by_name(rtpbin, "get-internal-session", 0, &session);`

Then I can use the `RTPSession` object to access and set properties like `rtcp-min-interval` or callback another function when a signal like `on-receiving-rtcp` is emitted.

How can I do the same using `webrtcbin`? Are the properties/signals of the `RTPSession` object somehow accessible from `webrtcbin` (1.18)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure actually. But since it is a bin, can you perhaps use `gst_bin_iterate_elements()` on it to iterate all other elements in the bin? I would expect the `rtpbin` to appear there at least once, depending on how many of them are being used within the webrtc bin intself.

Comment: Good point. Also, there seems to be a more direct way by using something like `rtpbin = gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN (webrtcbin), "rtpbin");` as answered [here](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Accessing-RTPSession-inside-webrtcbin-td4697431.html).

Comment: Correct. Note however these may not be static names. E.g. are often appended by an integer like `rtpbin0` and may change when a pipeline gets stopped/started. In the particular `webrtcbin` it may work though, just don't rely on names too much though.